# Do automorphisms generate any specific equivalence?

Tags: relations, predicate-logic

I am thinking about a structure (in terms of predicate logic), where we have a carrier set A and some relations over A (no functions). I am thinking about all the automorphisms for that structure.

I decided to define the binary relation $E(x,y)$ over A, such that $E(x,y)$ holds, when there exists an automorphism $f$, such that $f(x)=y$.

Is such E an equivalence relation? (to me, it seems like it is). Does such relation E have any specific mathematical name?

It also works for structures with functions. Most structures would have no automorphisms (just the identity), so E would be the equality (not interesting). But in many cases, E can create interesting equivalence classes on the carrier set (two elements of A are in the same equivalence class, when they have the same "role" within a structure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E(x,y)$ is an equivalence relation, given that the automorphisms of $A$, $Aut(A)$, form a group under composition of functions. So, $E(x,x)$, for $id(x)$ $\in Aut(A)$; $E(x,y) \implies E(y,x)$, since for every automorphism $f$, there is an inverse $f^{-1}$ which is also an automorphism (by the fact that $Aut(A)$ is a group), and $E(x,y), E(y,z) \implies E(x,z)$, for $Aut(A)$ is closed under composition of functions.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se].
Thank you for your answer.
Can you please [edit] your post and improve the math formatting using 
[LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020)?
By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on 
[answer] and on 
[formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) .

Answer (score 0):

This is called the **orbit equivalence relation**.

More generally, suppose we have a group $G$ [acting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) on a set $X$. Then we get an equivalence relation on $X$ given by this action, the *orbit equivalence relation*, where $$x\sim y\quad\iff\quad\exists g\in G: gx=y.$$ The *orbit* of an element $x\in X$ with respect to this action is the set $\{gx: g\in G\}$. Obviously different groups, or even different actions by the same group, can give rise to different orbit equivalence relations.

In the particular case you describe, $X$ is the underlying set of some structure $\mathfrak{X}$ and $G$ is the group of automorphisms of $\mathfrak{X}$ acting on $X$ in the obvious way.